# railsbricks gem - railties error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've messed with the `railsbricks (3.1.1)` settings as much as possible and still come across the same error whenever I run `rails s` or `rails -v` inside of my app:

```
/Users/swills/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/swills/Documents/projects/thingybob/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/swills/.rvm/rubies/ruby 2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/swills/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /Users/swills/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/swills/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/swills/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

This is only inside of my railsbricks generated app. Any other rails generated app runs as expected with `rails s` and `rails -v`.

Comment: The error message clearly says: `Could not find 'railties' (>= 0)`. Did you try to add/install `railties`?